# Searching for a string in a BST (c)

Tags: c, tree

I have a Binary Search Tree already made, and each node contains a name of a person. I'd like to make a loop in main that allows me to search if a name I enter is within the BST.
I wrote this function:

```
int find(Node* root, char* search) {

  if (root != NULL) {

    
        if(strcmp((root->name), search) == 0)
      return 1;

   
    if (strcmp(root->name, search) < 0)
      return find(root->left, search);

 
    else
      return find(root->right, search);

  }
  else
    return 0;
}
```

My intention is to return 1 if found, return 0 otherwise.
My main function has this loop:

```
char choice[30];
while(1){
    printf("Enter a word to search: ");
    scanf("%s", choice);

    int result = find(root, choice);
    if(result == 1){
        printf("Found.");
    }
    else{
        printf("Not found.");
    }

    printf("\n");
}
```

For some reason, it is only working (prints Found) for the first name in my BST, (the root).
Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `strcmp(root->name, search) < 0`, then it means root->name is 'less' than search, and you should look right, not left.

I think you've just got the direction of your search back to front! Where you recurse left, you should be recursing right, and vice versa.